# Setting MySQL DB size through PHP

Tags: mysql, php

My host's technical support sent me the following in reply to a suggestion to the sales team about the number and size of default MySQL databases. Specifically, I was suggesting to the sales team that the host could do better by offering fewer databases at larger sizes than many databases at small sizes, in context to how quickly a blog or board could fill a 100MB DB:

> You can edit the PHP.ini file in your SSH access to actually administer your database size limitations. If you wish to have 50, 100MB each or 5, 1000MB each there is no problem doing so. You will be required to set up these configurations on your own, however you are able to do so.

However, the details of this are not outlined in the email (I've followed up, but thought I would ask SO experts while I wait). I'm not much of a PHP expert or MySQL admin, but dangerous at the command line (most familiar with PostgreSQL). I wasn't even aware you could direct MySQL though the `php.ini`

Anyone want to take this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any PHP setting to limit the number or size of MySQL databases. Hosts sometimes put user limits on disk space where database data is stored. In any case, the sales rep may have been mistaking the php.ini settings for upload and POST limits that often impeded uploading SQL files to phpMyAdmin in shared hosting environments.

Comment: That's what I thought, but he/she was pretty specific in context. My suggestion of 5 x 1GB DBs is even copied verbatim. Why would I want to limit the upload by number and size, or the POST limit the same? Odd. Hoping for detailed reply from host.